# howto play 2 audio files grouped together after click selection

Tags: jquery, audio

With the help of stackoverflow guys I've got this jquery code going which plays selected audio files after clicking on English (or Thai) text.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var audioIsPlaying = false;
  jQuery("span.audio").click(function (evnt) {
    if(audioIsPlaying !== true) {
      var elementId = evnt.target.id;
      var pathVar = document.getElementById("pathVar").innerHTML;
      var oggVar = pathVar+elementId+".ogg";
      var audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
      audioElement.setAttribute("src", oggVar);    
      audioElement.play();
      audioIsPlaying = true;
      audioElement.addEventListener("ended", function() {
        audioIsPlaying = false;    
      });
    };
  });
});
```

This works great, thanks. But I need to select from 2 lists by clicking on English words

```
I can          go
I can't        walk
I will         play
I won't        speak
etc            etc
```

and then play back the 2 audio files as a sequence like "I can go", "I can walk" and so on.

I can see that the above code could be split into select phase and a play phase at audioElement.play(). I thought that if audio files could be loaded into an array as they were selected then they could be later read from the array and played back as a sequence. 
I'm a bit lost beyond this point. Any help would be very welcome